# C# MySql Login Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql

```
      using (var con = new MySqlConnection("host=*;user=*;password=*;database=*;"))
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nume, pass FROM users WHERE nume = @UserName AND pass = @Password";


            con.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    var username = reader.GetString(0);
                    button1.Visible = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You Login Information is incorrect!");
                }

            }

        }
```

I can register accounts in the db(from the website) but i cannot connect from c#.I Also tried other MySql Connectors but i keep getting error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: Can you check the bind-address of the db?

Comment: I Don't know that a bind adress is xD neither how i check it

Comment: Can you reach the host adress by ping? (win-R, cmd, ping yourHost) and is it a real server or just localhost?

Comment: It is a real server, the host is : mysql.hostinger.ro, this addres is not reached by ping my host's ip adress is reached.I can register accounts in the db and login on the website,but I can not login from c#

Answer (score 0):

Setting `CommandText` resets the `Parameters` collection. Try putting that at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It is may be your port is not opened for mysql transaction, I've just tried to open the port 3306 following these steps: Windows 7 users,

1. Open Control Panel from the Start menu.
2. Select Windows Firewall.
3. Select Advanced settings in the left column of the Windows Firewall window.
4. Select Inbound Rules in the left column of the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security window.
5. Select New Rule in the right column.
6. Select Port in the New Inbound Rule Wizard and then click Next.
7. Select which protocol this rule will apply to (TCP or UDP), select Specific local ports, type a port number (80), port numbers (80,81), or a range of port numbers (5000-5010) and then click Next.
8. Select Allow the connection and then click Next.
9. Select when this rule applies (check all of them for the port to always stay open) and then click Next.
10. Give this rule a name and then click Finish to add the new rule.